React Native iOS app images disappear suddenly
I am facing a very weird issue in my react native application specifically in iOS device and sometimes in simulator as well. Most of the time app works well but sometimes suddenly all the images in the app start disappearing except the local assets images and then if user keeps on switching the tabs in the app or re-installs the app the images come back as normal. My current react native version is "0.72.4". This issue is very hard to replicate, what could be the possible reasons, is it something related to pods ?
I tried updating my podfile with some post_install script for RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m but it actually didn't work out.

would like to know more about your implementations as well, add your code snippet here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This issue is happening for my whole react native application not any specific component, should I share my package.json ?
